# Proof that this is not a secure pseudorandom function?

Tags: cryptanalysis, algorithm-design, pseudo-random-function

> $p$ is a large prime number. Consider the following function $F:\mathbb Z^*_p \times \mathbb D\rightarrow\mathbb Z^*_p$ where $\mathbb D=2,....,p-1$.
>
> $F_k(x)=x^k \bmod p$
>
> Proof that it's not a secure pseudorandom function.

**What I‘ve tried:**

I give a value to $x_1$ and obtain $y_1$, then I set  $x_2 =y_1+p$. At the end $y_1$ is equal to $y_2$. Could this be right or is it  totally wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: multiplicative property.

What you have tried does not work because $y_1=y_2$ does not hold in general when $x_2=y_1+p$ (further, adding $p$ is identity in $Z_p$ ).

You want to build a distinguisher for $F_k$. Arguably, $F_k(1)=1$ is enough for that, but you can build a more general distinguisher from $F_k(x_1\cdot x_2\bmod p)=F_k(x_1)\cdot F_k(x_2)\bmod p$.